# Automatically update the code if there is a new version on github

Tags: python

I wonder if there is anyway to automatically update the code and folder if there is a newer version on github? I think it's not possible with Python and only possible for php.

Comment: Well yes. There are several ways. I personally just have a cron job in my raspberry pi that every 5 minutes pulls some of my repos. It's a very dirty way but it works and it's the easiest to configure. You can also use github's webhooks to call an endpoint of yours that pulls the changes whenever you've pushed a commit. There are many ways, just find one that suits you.

Comment: How about a listener script?

Comment: What makes you think it's not possible to do it in Python? What have you tried? Formulate your question in a way that we understand where you are stuck. Otherwise, it seems you are just writing a thought.

Answer (score -1):

Use GitHub API https://api.github.com/ and check the commits then pull from github?
Documents here: https://docs.github.com/en/rest
Request `https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}/commits` to get all the commits